# How can i choose one random item from an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, random

I tried the following code, but yet it didn't work:

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

<script>

var max=1000;
var text=new Array();
var i=0;

for (i; i<=max ; i++) {
    text[i]=i;
}
var newx0=new Array();
newx0.push(text);
var rand = newx0[Math.floor(Math.random() * newx0.length)];
var randomx0=newx0[Math.floor(Math.random()* newx0.length)];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = rand;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = newx0;
```

The proglem is the rand valuable prints 0 to 1000 just like the newx0 valuable

Comment: Can you tidy up your code (ie close the tags etc so it's complete) and explain what doesn't work about it?

Comment: `text` is already an array, but then you push that array into another array `newx0` - is this intentional?

Comment: `newx0.push(text);` this is why.

Comment: The problem is the rand valuable prints 0 to 1000 just like the newx0 valuable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new0` is an array, which contains one element: your other `text` array. That means `newx0.length` is always `1`. Why are you doing that array wrapper anyways? Why not just have

```
var rand = text[Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length)];
           ^^^^                            ^^^^
```

instead?

Comment: and is it possible that: now i have 0 to 1000...and i also need more 4x time...so i have to an array with number 0 to 1000 and 5 times...example 0,....1000, 0, ....,1000 so on?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Returns a random integer between min (inclusive) and max (inclusive)
 * Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
 */
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var array = [wherever your array comes from];     //Set up your array to be sampled
var randIndex = getRandomInt(0, array.length());  //Randomly select an index within the array's range
var randSelectedObj = array[randIndex];           //Access the element in the array at the selected index
```

getRandomInt was taken from here:
[Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)